# Bootstrap collapse is collapsing instantly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When I collapse my div, it collapses instantly. However, when I expand it, it expands with the sliding animation... I've got no idea why!

*Note: I have a lot of div's because I have removed a lot of the code to demonstrate the problem*

I'm using the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute.

I've figured out that it has something to do with: `pull-left` and if I add  `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after all `pull-left` then it fixes it. Unfortunately, I need the floats...

Can someone please help me?

Here is a JSFiddle with the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/xNkS5/33/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

Added `<div class="clearfix"></div>` after the closing tag of `<div class="traincard-body pull-left">`

Here is the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/xNkS5/35/